# Tumblr API: OAuth issue. Allow/Deny buttons and other tips

Tags: ios, oauth, tumblr

Issues about OAuth:

Tumblr put a big pin in my eyes, when I trying to deploy OAuth.

Ok, now I do this. (I think, that I do, not sure).

Questions about Tumblr:

1. Am I right, that after ACCESS_TOKEN POST-ed, Tumblr send back only token and token_secret  ?
2. If I "Deny" application, tumblr use url: =">http://example.com/callback#*=*  ?
3. If I "Allow" application, tumblr use your example url with parameters "oauth_token" and "oauth_verifier" ?
4. If I "Allow" application, tumblr want to redirect to callback url?
5. If I "Deny" or "Allow" application twice ( I prevent tumblr to redirect to callback_url), tumblr start to load: http://www.tumblr.com/dashboard ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find answers for my questions.

1. YES, this is true. Access_token POST-ed and server send it back to me
2. YES, If I "Deny" application, tumblr use url: CALLBACK_URL with oauth_token and oauth_verifier with zero-values (NULL values)
3. YES, If I "Allow" application, tumblr sent me back oauth_token and oauth_verifier (You must use them to get Access_token)
4. If I "Allow" application, tumblr REDIRECT to CALLBACK_URL (so, catch it).
5. If I "Deny" or "Allow" application twice, tumblr start to load: http://www.tumblr.com/dashboard.

P.S:

If I need to RELOGIN user, I need to logout from tumblr with this URL:

http://www.tumblr.com/logout